# Delete rows between values of a column

Tags: r, rows

I have a very large data frame, I want to delete the rows between the values of one column by id, but only if they are inside this values, not at beginning nor end. In the example I want to delete the rows or='base' between rows or='plan'

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
fd <- c(101,102,103,104,105,106,101,102,103,104,105,106)
rem <- c(100,120,120,140, 140, 150, 200,220,220,250, 300, 310)
or <- c("base", "base", "plan", "base", "plan", "base", "plan", "base", 
"plan", "base", "plan", "base")
df <- data.frame(id, fd, rem, or)
```

Result:

```
id1 <- c(rep(1,5), rep(2,4))
fd1 <- c(101,102,103,106, 107, 101,103,105,106)
or1 <- c("base", "base", "plan", "plan", "base", "plan", "plan", "plan", "base")

df1 <- data.frame(id1,fd1,or1)
```

Comment: What if you have several instances of  'base'/'plan' for some id

Comment: I want to delete every rows between 'plan' for the same id. For example to the id 1, I want to leave the first two 'base' and the last one (before id 2 starts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

**1) Using base R:**

```
idx <- ave(df$or, df$id, FUN = function(x) x=='base' & c('base',head(x,-1))=='plan' & c(tail(x,-1),'base')=='plan')=='FALSE'
df[idx,]
```

which gives:

```
   id  fd rem   or
1   1 101 100 base
2   1 102 120 base
3   1 103 120 plan
5   1 105 140 plan
6   1 106 150 base
7   2 101 200 plan
9   2 103 220 plan
11  2 105 300 plan
12  2 106 310 base
```

**2) Using the `data.table`-package:**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

idx <- df[, .I[!(or=='base' & shift(or, fill = 'base')=='plan' & shift(or, fill = 'base', type = 'lead')=='plan')], id]$V1
df[idx]
```

which gives:

```
   id  fd rem   or
1:  1 101 100 base
2:  1 102 120 base
3:  1 103 120 plan
4:  1 105 140 plan
5:  1 106 150 base
6:  2 101 200 plan
7:  2 103 220 plan
8:  2 105 300 plan
9:  2 106 310 base
```

Or in one go:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[!(or=='base' & shift(or, fill = 'base')=='plan' & shift(or, fill = 'base', type = 'lead')=='plan')], id]$V1]
```

---

In response to the comment, you can use the `rle`-function to detect more than one `'base'`-rows between `'plan'`-rows as follows (in base R):

```
# create new example dataset
df2 <- df[c(1:3,4,4,5:7,8,8,9:12),]

# the new example dataset:
> df2
    id  fd rem   or
1    1 101 100 base
2    1 102 120 base
3    1 103 120 plan
4    1 104 140 base
4.1  1 104 140 base
5    1 105 140 plan
6    1 106 150 base
7    2 101 200 plan
8    2 102 220 base
8.1  2 102 220 base
9    2 103 220 plan
10   2 104 250 base
11   2 105 300 plan
12   2 106 310 base

# define function
f <- function(x) {
  rl <- rle(x)
  rl$values <- !(rl$values == 'base' & c('base',head(rl$values,-1))=='plan' & c(tail(rl$values,-1),'base')=='plan')
  inverse.rle(rl)
}

# apply the function to each id-group and create an index
idx2 <- as.logical(ave(df2$or, df2$id, FUN = f))

# finally subset your data with the logical-index
df2[idx2,]
```

which gives:

```
> df2[idx2,]
   id  fd rem   or
1   1 101 100 base
2   1 102 120 base
3   1 103 120 plan
5   1 105 140 plan
6   1 106 150 base
7   2 101 200 plan
9   2 103 220 plan
11  2 105 300 plan
12  2 106 310 base
```

Another option in base R (inspired by @Frank's data.table suggestion in the comments):

```
f2 <- function(x) {
  i <- seq_along(x)
  w <- which(x == 'plan')
  b <- which(x == 'base')
  ib <- b[b > head(w,1) & b < tail(w,1)]
  !(i %in% ib)
}

idx3 <- unlist(by(df2$or, df2$id, f2))
df2[idx3,]
```

With `data.table` you could follow @Frank's suggestion:

```
setDT(df2)
df2[, keep := {isp = or == "plan"; wp = which(isp); r = 1:.N; isp | r < first(wp) | r > last(wp)}, by = id
    ][!!keep]
```

---

Used data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
                     fd = c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106), 
                     rem = c(100, 120, 120, 140, 140, 150, 200, 220, 220, 250, 300, 310), 
                     or = c("base", "base", "plan", "base", "plan", "base", "plan", "base", "plan", "base", "plan", "base")), 
                .Names = c("id", "fd", "rem", "or"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Any idea how can I modify the code to delete rows when after 'plan' I have two or more rows whit 'base' and then 'plan' again. Thanks

Comment: Instead of finding which ones to drop, you could ID those to keep (all "plan" and all before first plan or after last plan), like `df[, keep := {isp = or == "plan"; wp = which(isp); r = 1:.N; isp | r < first(wp) | r > last(wp)}, by=id]` or something like that.

Comment: @Frank thx & updated (including a 2nd base R approach inspired by yours)